# What is this sequence for this analog of Engel products?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, infinite-product

I was looking for a product analog of Engel expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion
and came up with this new type of expansion of a number.

We start with a number $0<x_1<1$.

Then find integer $n_1$ such that
$$
1-\frac{1}{n_1-1}<x_1<1-\frac{1}{n_1},
$$
Then write
$$
x_1=\left(1-\frac{1}{n_1}\right)x_2, \quad 0<x_2<1.
$$
Then continue the process using recurrence
$$
n_k=1+\lfloor\frac{1}{1-x_{k}}\rfloor.
$$
For example we get
$$
\frac{\pi}{4}=\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{55}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{13931}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2811273900}\right)\\\times \left(1-\frac{1}{75684454671917856333}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{17449196642525545927189430934592764076742}\right)\times \ldots
$$

I looked this sequence in oeis but it did not return any results.

Also it seems like $(n_k)^{2^{-k}}$ should have a limit, but the numebrs grow very fast and this limit does not converge fast enough to calculate or check if it really tends to some limit.

> Q: has representations of this kind been studied before? Can you prove the limit exits and find the limit $\lim(n_k)^{2^{-k}}$, $k\to\infty$?

Comment: You don't mention the keyword "infinite product" that you can use to attempt to find similar issues.

Comment: If $x_1=1/2$, what is $n_1$? (I.e., I don't think you want strict inequality on both sides of the expression defining $n_1$, unless you explicitly limit things to irrational values of $x$.)

Comment: @BarryCipra good catch. I will edit when will have time.

Comment: I think you may want to simply define $n_k=\lceil1/(1-x_k)\rceil$, using the ceiling function, and then $x_{k+1}=n_kx_k/(n_k-1)$. This would lead to terminating expansions for rationals such as $7/11=(1-1/3)(1-1/22)$ (and agrees with the floor definition when $1/(1-x_k)$ is not an integer, which is always the case if $x_1$ is irrational).

Comment: Some of these representations can be found in OEIS: $1/\pi$ [A092388](https://oeis.org/A092388), $1/\Phi$ [A088334](https://oeis.org/A088334) or $\exp(-1)$ [A092389](https://oeis.org/A092389).